# Is there a way to persist dateparts Week and DayOfWeek in computed column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

To speed and simplify aggregation of data queries for a dashboard, I have added these additional date columns as computed columns derived from a date field when the record is inserted.

These 3 are created from **`(CONVERT([varchar],[DateCreated], (112)))`** or a `substring` of such. Persisting works. No problem.

`YearUTC`

`YearMonthUTC`

`YearMonthDayUTC`

However, with these 2, I receive the error

> Cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

**`WEEK(DATEPART(WEEK, [DateCreated]))`**

**`DAYOFWEEK(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DateCreated]))`**

If cannot persist, I'm afraid the cost would be too great with large table (500K rows). Is there a work-around?

**EIDT: Sorry, I was not using GetDate() in my real code. I should have changed that to a standard field, [DateCreated]. I updated my code above. Even with a standard date field that is known when the record is created, I get the same error.**

Comment: `getdate()` obviously makes this non deterministic. You say these should be derived from a date field. What happens if you actually do that?

Comment: @hvd - and the fact that these two components are [specifically listed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments) to depend on the `DATEFIRST` setting

Comment: Consider creating a calendar table *instead*. You can then populate that, as a one-off exercise with say 20 years worth of data (1 row per day, 20 years is still less than 10000 rows) and then *join* to that table when you need this sort of component extraction. They won't be computed columns in the calendar table either but that doesn't matter since it's *static* data.

Comment: @Damien Ah, right, so that wasn't even the biggest problem.

Comment: The classic workaround in such cases is to use a trigger that, on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, writes the required value into a regular column. This isn't as elegant as a computed column, but unfortunately necessary in the absence of a deterministic `DATEPART` equivalent function. (Technically you could write such a function, but it's hardly worth the bother.)

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the `week` part [sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52340770/11683), you can also create a (much simpler than it would be for the `week`) function for the `weekday` bit:

```
-- Monday is always 1 and so on
create function WeekdayAbsolute(@d datetime)
returns int
with schemabinding, returns null on null input
as
begin
  declare @b int;

  -- The zero date (i.e. cast(0 as datetime)) was Monday. Therefore...
  set @b = 1 + ((datediff(d, @d - @d, @d)) % 7);
  if @b > 7 set @b = @b - 7;

  return @b;
end;
```

and use it in the column expression.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution to the Week datepart. Use (datepart, ISO_WEEK, [datefield]) instead of (datepart, week, [datefield]) and you can persist the value. One more reason to hate on the nuances of time however, “*The numbering systems of different countries/regions might not comply with the ISO standard*.”

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
```

The solution I went with for the DayOfWeek was to create an after update trigger as suggested by @Jeroen_Mostert